# What does "finding the sequence of $2$ matrices" mean?

Tags: matrices

The study guide that I am following says "The output is the sequence of the two matrices $B1$: \begin{bmatrix}0&2\\0&2\end{bmatrix} and $B2$: $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 2 & 7\\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 5\\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 7\\
    0 & 4 & 2 & 7
  \end{pmatrix}
$$"

What does "the sequence of two matrices" mean? Is it multiplication?

Also, please add more resources for me to study more about this.

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHHG5.png)
[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lapCK.png)
[part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP5Rk.png)

Comment: Can you add context?  What book is it?  And what were they saying before that?

Comment: Add the original resource, many times the terminology used in some notes, is not correct or at least standard so it could be any operation.

Comment: If the matrices had the same sizes, I'd assume they simply meant the product of the two matrices. But these matrices don't have the correct dimensions to multiply.

Comment: This is about Hierarchical (Pyramid) Coding algorithms. Pyramid Coding is an image compression technique for progressive transmission of large images to remote viewers. Typically the viewers need to select from a large number of images received online. To speed up the selection process, a viewer might prefer to receive highlights of each image promptly
rather than each detailed image slowly. Hence, instead of sending the pixels of an image line by line, the sender sends a sequence of ‘representatives’ of the image pixels as the highlights using the Pyramid Coding scheme.

Comment: I have added a few images.

Comment: Might it just be a sequence of length 2? That is, a pair.

Comment: By "sequence" they just mean a list of matrices. This list has two matrices. The first is a $2\times 2$ and the second is a $4 \times 4$. They do not operate on each other. Instead, the first matrix is a "lower-resolution" version of the second matrix. Each "pixel" in the first matrix corresponds to a block of four "pixels" in the second.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Also thank you others for your time as well.